# Chart data javascript

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I would like to make chart in javascript with my data but I don't know how.
Here is chart which I would like to use: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/professional-candlesticks/ :

and inside code I found something like this:

```
{"dataProvider": [ {
"date": "2011-08-01",
"open": "136.65",
"high": "136.96",
"low": "134.15",
"close": "136.49"
```

}

etc.
I load data to php array:

```
<?php $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../projekt/lataset_2009.csv'));?>
```

VALUES in CSV:

DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE

then I use javascript code:`var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($csv); ?>;`
 to rewrit php array to javascript array
AND here is problem:
How to change

date": "2011-08-01",

"open": "136.65",

"high": "136.96",

"low": "134.15",

"close": "136.49"

with array data. 
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten the solution as the data in an multidimensional array this will work:

```
//get the csv data
$records = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../projekt/lataset_2009.csv'));

//create empty array
$data = array();

//loop through the csv data
foreach($records as $row){

    //ignore the first array line so only the lines containing the data is used
    if($row[0] != 'date'){ 

        //create an array into the parent $data array
        $data[] = array(
            'date' => $row[0],
            'open' => $row[1],
            'high' => $row[2],
            'low' => $row[3],
            'close' => $row[4],
        );
    }   
}

//turn the array to json
$chartData = json_encode($data);

//alter the date so it's in a valid date format
$chartData = str_replace('\/', '/', $chartData);

//output the data
echo $chartData;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I put your code and still have problem. Loaded file show "trying to get property of non-object in..... line 12

Comment: put your code and still have problem. Loaded file show "trying to get property of non-object in..... line 12

My php code now is
`<?php

    $records = array_map('str_getcsv', file(''../projekt/lataset_2009.csv''));

        $chartdata = null;

    foreach ($records as $row) {

    $chartdata.="{date: \"$row->date\", open: \"$row->open\", high: \"$row->high\", low: \"$row->low\", close: \"$row->close\"},";
    } `
My JS code is :

 `"dataProvider": [<?=$chartdata;?>]`
And I still looking solution because is doesn't work.

Comment: I've changed the answer so it's based on your CSV and not database date as it was before.

Comment: thanks. It's working. Next step is to add chart with lines to candelstick chart. Also with amcharts.

Comment: Sorry for delay but I was looing button accept, haha.

Comment: Maybe a litle bit more of help? I would like to add to this candlestick chart lines. Data are located in CSV in next 4 columns. So CSV is now DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4. How I can see this. Default chart is DATE,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,Value1,Value2 and if I click on hyperlink / button V1 and V2 disapear and show Value 3 Value 4. This page is a litle complicated